# How to extract file name from URL?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, looker-studio, re2

I have file names in a URL and want to strip out the preceding URL and filepath as well as the version that appears after the `?`

**[Sample URL](https://www.dudesolutions.com/Portals/0/Documents/CaptialForecasting_Datasheet.pdf?ver=2018-03-18-122940-753)**

Trying to use RegEx to pull, `CaptialForecasting_Datasheet.pdf`

The `REGEXP_EXTRACT` in Google Data Studio seems unique. Tried the suggestion but kept getting "*could not parse*" error.  I was able to strip out the first part of the url with the following.  `Event Label` is where I store URL of downloaded PDF.

The URL:

```
https://www.dudesolutions.com/Portals/0/Documents/HC_Brochure_Digital.pdf?ver=2018-03-18-110927-033
```

`REGEXP_EXTRACT( Event Label , 'Documents/([^&]+)' )`

The result:

```
HC_Brochure_Digital.pdf?ver=2018-03-18-110927-033
```

Now trying to determine how do I pull out everything after the`?` where the version data is, so as to extract just the `Filename.pdf`.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried all of the 3 answers and their variations but Google Data Studio would not parse the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name appears right after the last `/` and ends with the `?`, the regular expression below will leave the name in group 1 where you can get it with `\1` or whatever the tool that you are using supports.

```
.*\/(.*)\?
```

It basically says: get everything in between the last `/` and the first `?` after, and put it in group 1.

Another regular expression that only matches the file name that you want but is more complex is:

```
(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=\?)
```

It matches all non-`/` characters, `[^\/]`, immediately preceded by `/`, `(?<=\/)` and immediately followed by `?`, `(?=\?)`. The first parentheses is a positive lookbehind, and the second expression in parentheses is a positive lookahead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but Google Data Studio gives me error that it cannot parse.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

[`[^\/]+(?=\?[^\/]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/SDEQos/2)

This will match `CaptialForecasting_Datasheet.pdf` even if there is a question mark in the path. For example, the regex will succeed in both of these cases:

```
https://www.dudesolutions.com/somepath/CaptialForecasting_Datasheet.pdf?ver
https://www.dudesolutions.com/somepath?/CaptialForecasting_Datasheet.pdf?ver
```

Answer (score 0):

This [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) formula captures the characters `a-zA-Z0-9_.` between `/` and `?`

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Event Label, "/([\\w\\.]+)\\?")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ac9b46ef-eeb6-4698-be0b-4ae558ad7d89) to demonstrate.

[image: 3]]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following regex
`[A-Za-z\_]*.pdf`

I have tried it online at https://regexr.com/. Attaching the screenshot for reference
[image]

Please note that this only works for .pdf files

Answer (score -2):

Following regex will extract file name with `.pdf` extension

```
(?:[^\/][\d\w\.]+)(?<=(?:.pdf))
```

You can add more extensions like this,

```
(?:[^\/][\d\w\.]+)(?<=(?:.pdf)|(?:.jpg))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jv8CAq/1)